# "Access of undefined property" error in a static initializer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, initialization

I wish to initialize two static `ArrayList` objects in an ActionScript static initializer.

I wrote this code :

```
import mx.collections.ArrayList;

public class Problem{

    [Bindable] private static var levelNumbers:ArrayList;
    [Bindable] private static var speedNumbers:ArrayList;

    {
        for (var loopInt:int = 1; loopInt<901; loopInt++){
            levelNumbers.addItem(loopInt);
            speedNumbers.addItem(loopInt);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

But the code won't compile. I get this error in the three lines of the `for` loop:

`1120 : Access of undefined property loopInt`

Why is that so? I just defined the variable as usual!

Comment: It seems like there is some code missing from this example. Where is the function declared?

Comment: @jerem do you mean `getTimer()` ? It is a built-in function, found at `flash.utils`. I remove it for clarity then.

Comment: It was not the getTimer() call that was throwing me off, it was the fact that your function wrapping the for loop had no declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually the local `loopInt` variable in your code. When using static intialisers, you can't use `this`, the name of the class, or local variables. The first two is probably because the class doesn't fully exist yet, while the last one, I'm not sure about (perhaps there's no scope?).

To make it work, extract your loop to a function. Like this:

```
{
    _init();
}

private static function _init():void
{
    for (var loopInt:int = 1; loopInt<901; loopInt++){
        levelNumbers.addItem(loopInt);
        speedNumbers.addItem(loopInt);
    }
}
```

and it should work

Comment: I just tested this and it works well. I also found that you don't need the curly braces that wrap the call to _init().

Comment: There is a normal scope in the static initializer, it's just that you can't declare local variables there with ActionScript.  Also, adding curly braces does nothing to the scope, so `var loopInt` is seen as an instance property.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because there is no ArrayList in Flex .You mean ArrayCollection.This code below should work fine.

> public class Problem{
>   [Bindable] private static var levelNumbers:ArrayCollection;
>   [Bindable] private static var speedNumbers:ArrayCollection;
>   {         trace(" 1 " + getTimer());
>   for (var loopInt:int = 1; loopInt<901; loopInt++){
>    levelNumbers.addItem(loopInt);
>   speedNumbers.addItem(loopInt);         }
>   trace(" 2 " + getTimer() + "\n\n");     }      //... }

Comment: There is an `ArrayList` in Flex at `mx.collections`. I added the import.